Docker tarda mucho en instalar dependencias NodeJS en un servidor
Tengo un problema cuando intento construir una imagen de un proyecto de Nodejs en un servidor de 1GB RAM. Cuando llega a la capa de instalacion de paquetes con RUN npm i, se queda intentando instalarlos durante muchas horas hasta que me canso de esperar y mato el proceso.
PD: Solo sucede en servidores, he probado con AWS de 1GB y DigitalOcean tambien de 1GB
No puedo aumentar los recursos porque es un trabajo de universidad.
Alguna solución?
Dockerfile:
FROM node:20.12.2

RUN mkdir /app_temp

WORKDIR /app_temp

RUN npm install -g pm2 copyfiles

COPY package.json .
RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

RUN mkdir -p /app_temp/dist/init

RUN cp ./init/init-prod.sh /app_temp/dist/init

RUN rm -rf /app

RUN mv /app_temp/dist/ /app

WORKDIR /app

RUN npm install

RUN rm -rf /app_temp

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["bash", "init/init-prod.sh"]


cómo estás creando tu imagen, si tienes un dockerfile agrégalo a la pregunta

¿Has visto algún log?

Creo que ese problema puede venir de la imagen, pues node:20.12.2 ocupa 1.1Gb. puedes probar con alguna otra imagen (como la node:20.12.2-alpine, que son 135Mb) pero eso ya según tú proyecto

Lamentablemente no creo que haya mucho que optimizar. Node gasta bastante RAM durante la construcción de un proyecto.
¿Sería viable para ti construir la imagen en tu equipo u otro dispositivo, subir la imagen a dockerhub por ejemplo y luego descargar la imagen en el servidor y ejecutarla?
Un saludo.
